# JavaScript/React Auto-filling other fields based one the first one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**1.** I have array of 12 indexes "**listOfPaysIndexes**", I am using this array to iterate through her and render 12 DateInput fields.

**2.** You can click on each of this fields and pick Date.

**3.** When you pick date in first DateInput all the others DateInputs should be auto-filled with that value.

Which is best way to implement that in react javascript?

Here is code:

```
 {*You can see here that listOfPaysIndexes which have 12 indexes.
   For every index there is one DateInput. *}

   {listOfPaysIndexes.map(value => {
      return (
        <Form.Group
          widths="equal"
          key={`month_${value}`}
        >
          <Form.Field width={5}>
            {/*** HERE IS DATE FIELD ***/}
            <DateInput
              name={`ending_period_monthly[${value}]`}
              value={values.ending_period_monthly[value]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              dateFormat={'MM/DD/YYYY'}
            />
            )}
          </Form.Field>

        </Form.Group>
      )
    })}
```

Here is How that Date Inputs looks: 
[image]

Comment: You need to do this for only first date input?

Comment: @AvcS yes, only for first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something along these lines, this is just for idea I don't know your exact code, replace `this` with whatever you are using to refer the context and replace the method `getValueFromEvent` with whatever you are using to fetch value from event

```
handleChange(index, event) {
    if (index === 1) {
        listOfPaysIndexes.forEach(value => {
            values.ending_period_monthly[value] = getValueFromEvent(event);
        });
    }

    // handler for others
}

{listOfPaysIndexes.map(value => (
    <Form.Group
        widths="equal"
        key={`month_${value}`}
    >
        <Form.Field width={5}>
        {/*** HERE IS DATE FIELD ***/}
        <DateInput
            name={`ending_period_monthly[${value}]`}
            value={values.ending_period_monthly[value]}
            onChange={handleChange.bind(this, value)}
            dateFormat={'MM/DD/YYYY'}
        />
        )}
        </Form.Field>
    </Form.Group>
))}
```